# Create Customer with multiple addresses in Oracle EBS (12.1)

Tags: oracle-ebs

I'm trying to use the customer interface tables (RA_CUSTOMERS_INTERFACE_ALL) in Oracle EBS 12.1 to create a new customer with multiple addresses, and I'm not having any luck.

At this point, I can create the customer and only their BILL_TO address. However, when I add another entry to the interface table for their SHIP_TO and DELIVER_TO addresses, the interface program rejects them, with the following errors.

> DELIVER_TO: BILL_TO_ORIG_ADDRESS_REF should only be defined for
> Ship-to Addresses. You can define accounts only for a customer Bill-To
> site.
>
> SHIP_TO: You can define accounts only for a customer Bill-To site.

And here's a sample of the code I'm using to insert the records into the RA_CUSTOMERS_INTERFACE_ALL and RA_CUSTOMER_PROFILES_INT_ALL tables. In it, I'm just trying to associate the same address with all three address types, but ideally I'd also like to have the option of using different addresses.

```
-- BILL_TO
INSERT INTO APPS.RA_CUSTOMERS_INTERFACE_ALL (ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF,
                                         SITE_USE_CODE,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF,
                                         INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG,
                                         CUSTOMER_NAME,
                                         CUSTOMER_STATUS,
                                         PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF,
                                         LOCATION,
                                         ADDRESS1,
                                         CITY,
                                         STATE,
                                         PROVINCE,
                                         COUNTY,
                                         POSTAL_CODE,
                                         COUNTRY,
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1, --Customer Classification Code
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2, --Sales Channel
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5,
                                         CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE,
                                         LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                         LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                                         CREATED_BY,
                                         CREATION_DATE,
                                         ORG_ID,
                                         GL_ID_REC,
                                         GL_ID_REV)
VALUES (
             'EVAN1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF
             'BILL_TO', --SITE_USE_CODE
             'EVAN1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF
             'I', --INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG
             'EVAN TEST CUST 1', --CUSTOMER_NAME
             'A', --CUSTOMER_STATUS
             'Y', --PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG
             'PARENT1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF
             'EVAN TEST LOCATION', --LOCATION
             '123 TEST ST', --ADDRESS1
             'BEVERLY HILLS', --CITY
             'CA', --STATE
             'CA', --PROVINCE
             'COUNTY OF LOS ANGELES', --COUNTY
             '90210', --POSTAL_CODE
             'US', --COUNTRY
             'End User Customer',  --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1
             'DOMESTIC NON-OEM', --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2
             'BILL_TO', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY
             '1', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5
             'CUSTOMER', --CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE
             1111, --LAST_UPDATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --LAST_UPDATE_DATE
             1111, --CREATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --CREATION_DATE
             111, --ORG_ID
             1111, --GL_ID_REC
             1111 --GL_ID_REV
);

-- SHIP_TO
INSERT INTO APPS.RA_CUSTOMERS_INTERFACE_ALL (ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF,
                                         SITE_USE_CODE,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF,
                                         INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG,
                                         CUSTOMER_NAME,
                                         CUSTOMER_STATUS,
                                         PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF,
                                         LOCATION,
                                         ADDRESS1,
                                         CITY,
                                         STATE,
                                         PROVINCE,
                                         COUNTY,
                                         POSTAL_CODE,
                                         COUNTRY,
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1, --Customer Classification Code
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2, --Sales Channel
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5,
                                         CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE,
                                         LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                         LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                                         CREATED_BY,
                                         CREATION_DATE,
                                         ORG_ID,
                                         GL_ID_REC,
                                         GL_ID_REV)
VALUES (
             'EVAN1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF
             'SHIP_TO', --SITE_USE_CODE
             'EVAN1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF
             'I', --INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG
             'EVAN TEST CUST 1', --CUSTOMER_NAME
             'A', --CUSTOMER_STATUS
             'Y', --PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG
             'PARENT1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF
             'EVAN TEST LOCATION', --LOCATION
             '123 TEST ST', --ADDRESS1
             'BEVERLY HILLS', --CITY
             'CA', --STATE
             'CA', --PROVINCE
             'COUNTY OF LOS ANGELES', --COUNTY
             '90210', --POSTAL_CODE
             'US', --COUNTRY
             'End User Customer',  --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1
             'DOMESTIC NON-OEM', --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2
             'SHIP_TO', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY
             '1', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5
             'CUSTOMER', --CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE
             1111, --LAST_UPDATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --LAST_UPDATE_DATE
             1111, --CREATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --CREATION_DATE
             111, --ORG_ID
             1111, --GL_ID_REC
             1111 --GL_ID_REV
);

--DELIVER_TO
INSERT INTO APPS.RA_CUSTOMERS_INTERFACE_ALL (ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF,
                                         SITE_USE_CODE,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF,
                                         INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG,
                                         CUSTOMER_NAME,
                                         CUSTOMER_STATUS,
                                         PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG,
                                         ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF,
                                         LOCATION,
                                         ADDRESS1,
                                         CITY,
                                         STATE,
                                         PROVINCE,
                                         COUNTY,
                                         POSTAL_CODE,
                                         COUNTRY,
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1, --Customer Classification Code
                                         ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2, --Sales Channel
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4,
                                         SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5,
                                         CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE,
                                         LAST_UPDATED_BY,
                                         LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                                         CREATED_BY,
                                         CREATION_DATE,
                                         ORG_ID,
                                         GL_ID_REC,
                                         GL_ID_REV)
VALUES (
             'EVAN1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF
             'DELIVER_TO', --SITE_USE_CODE
             'EVAN1', --ORGI_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF
             'I', --INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG
             'EVAN TEST CUST 1', --CUSTOMER_NAME
             'A', --CUSTOMER_STATUS
             'Y', --PRIMARY_SITE_USE_FLAG
             'PARENT1', --ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF
             'EVAN TEST LOCATION', --LOCATION
             '123 TEST ST', --ADDRESS1
             'BEVERLY HILLS', --CITY
             'CA', --STATE
             'CA', --PROVINCE
             'COUNTY OF LOS ANGELES', --COUNTY
             '90210', --POSTAL_CODE
             'US', --COUNTRY
             'End User Customer',  --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE1
             'DOMESTIC NON-OEM', --ADDRESS_ATTRIBUTE2
             'DELIVER_TO', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY
             '1', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE1
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE4
             'No', --SITE_USE_ATTRIBUTE5
             'CUSTOMER', --CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE
             1111, --LAST_UPDATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --LAST_UPDATE_DATE
             1111, --CREATED_BY
             SYSDATE, --CREATION_DATE
             111, --ORG_ID
             1111, --GL_ID_REC
             1111 --GL_ID_REV
);

INSERT INTO APPS.RA_CUSTOMER_PROFILES_INT_ALL (
    INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG,
    ORIG_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF,
    CUSTOMER_PROFILE_CLASS_NAME,
    CREDIT_HOLD,
    LAST_UPDATED_BY,
    LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
    CREATION_DATE,
    CREATED_BY,
    ORG_ID
) VALUES (
    'I', --INSERT_UPDATE_FLAG
    'EVAN1', --ORGI_SYSTEM_CUSTOMER_REF
    'MYPROFILE', --CUSTOMER_PROFILE_CLASS_NAME
    'Y', --CREDIT_HOLD
    1111, --LAST_UPDATED_BY
    SYSDATE, --LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    SYSDATE, --CREATION_DATE
    1111, --CREATED_BY
    111 --ORG_ID
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot more trial and error today, I was able to get it to work. For the non-Bill To addresses, I had to remove the following columns from the customer interface inserts:

- CUSTOMER_STATUS
- ORIG_SYSTEM_PARENT_REF
- CUSTOMER_CATEGORY_CODE
- GL_ID_REC
- GL_ID_REV

With those fields set to NULL, the customer interface program was able to successfully attach the additional addresses to my customer account. By modifying the ORIG_SYSTEM_ADDRESS_REF field, I was able to get it to either use the same address/location for all three, or create separate addresses/location for each type as required.